# syntax for late attendance query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get the amount of how often an employee is late

so far I've used this

```
SELECT  EMPID 
       ,EMPNAME
      ,COUNT(TimeIn) AS LATECOUNT  FROM        
 (SELECT  EMPLOYEEID AS EMPID, EmployeeName AS EMPNAME, AbsenceDate AS ABSDAT, MIN(TimeIn) AS TimeIn
   FROM  dbo.viewAttendance
         GROUP BY AbsenceDate, EMPLOYEEID, EmployeeName
         HAVING      (MIN(TimeIn) > '08:00:00')
  ) AS a
```

with that code, I can only retrieve the rows which only have employees who have late attendance at least one (only returns 30 rows). What I actually want is a full return of 300 rows ( all employees) displaying their amount of late attendance. My mind is not clear enough to find the correct syntax. I know the problem is at the HAVING     (MIN(timeIn) > '08:00:00'  can anyone help me? thanks in advance... :)

Comment: Do you have an employee table that you can join from?

Comment: Also, can an employee have more than one record for a single `AbsenceDate` on `viewAttendance`? Considering that the column name is `AbsenceDate`, if the employee clocks in on time, will there be a record at all? Is there a different column that is used if they clock in on time? If they don't show up at all on a day, is there a record for the employee with that `AbsenceDate` and no `TimeIn`? If you answer these questions, I think I can write the query for you. :)

Comment: yes, I have a `masterEmployee` table , and also, in `viewAttendance` , a employee can have more than one record for a single `absenceDate`. If a employee clocks in on time / less than 8:00 , a record will be made. And if they don't show up at all, there will be  no `absenceDate` , `timeIn` and `timeOut` at all. There is also one more thing, there are some employees whose `timeIn` is null, renders they can have no `timeIn`at all, or `timeIn` which is made after they return from lunchtime... I'd be glad with your help, thanks in adv :)

Comment: Is a redesign an option? It would seem to me more logical to have a schedule table as well as an attendance table. The former would specify when an employee *must* come to work, the other would show when and if they *actually* came. That way it should be much easier to count absence days as well as late attendance days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  E.EMPNAME
  ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN A.TIMEIN > '08:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS LATE_ATTENDANCE
FROM
 dbo.MASTEREMPLOYEE E
 LEFT JOIN dbo.viewATTENDANCE A ON A.EMPLOYEEID = E.EMPLOYEEID
```

Comment: ah this one is nice. I just need to alter a bit up to match my table. Thanks Dan

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like this:

```
select e.empname, (select count(1) from dbo.viewAttendance a where a.EmployeeId = e.employeeId and a.timein > '08:00:00') as latecount
from employees e
```